# Upload photo on facebook wall iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ipad, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am stuck in weird situation. I want to upload photo from my iPad app which will always shows on user's wall. I already tried with "facebook.photo.upload" method but for some reason it shows 1 photo on the user's wall and all other upload goes to album directly and doesn't appear on the user's wall. So I want to show all the photo on the user's wall.

So, Another scenario is I can use "stream.publish" and attach my photo in attachment parameter. But in this method I required URL of my UIImage which I don't have. Even If I manage URL still I guess my photo would be display as Thumbnail as all other stream shows. I want my photo preserve size 768X1004.

So, what is the best way to achieve this in iPhone sdk. I just want to upload my photo every time on user's wall. I don't mind whether it goes in album or not.

Thanks in Advance for help..

***Edit:***

I accomplish this by uploading photo to my own server and post that to user's wall using publish.stream. I did not get any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't get any solutions. So I accomplish this by uploading photo to my own server and post that to user's wall using publish.stream. I did not get any other way.

Comment: Hi Deeps Will u tell me how to achieve this , can u share some coding.

Comment: Hi Vijay, I uploaded actual image on server using API and API return me the URL of that photo and I used that url in "stream.publish". So this way I sort out my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method of Facebook graph api It will post photo on facebook wall

```
-(IBAction)postPictureButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];

    //create a UIImage (you could use the picture album or camera too)

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 8.0);
    UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    //create a FbGraphFile object insance and set the picture we wish to publish on it
    FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:picture];

    //finally, set the FbGraphFileobject onto our variables dictionary....
    [variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];

    [variables setObject:@"this is a test message: postPictureButtonPressed" forKey:@"message"];

    //the fbGraph object is smart enough to recognize the binary image data inside the FbGraphFile
    //object and treat that is such.....
    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"117795728310/photos" withPostVars:variables];
    NSLog(@"postPictureButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);

    NSLog(@"Now log into Facebook and look at your profile & photo albums...");

}
```

Comment: Thanks @IphoneDeveloper. I will give it a try now. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I just gave it a try and same problem. It uploads photo to album directly. If I delete Album and upload new photo it shows me on wall. It doesn't show after that. I need each time separate wall post for each photo I upload from iPad app. Is this something possible through Graph API ? Thanks

Comment: ok, I have not created any album on facebook. may be that's y mine is always goto wall post

Comment: I don't want to create album if it is possible without album. So what would be the "doGraphPost" parameter if I don't want Album ? Let me know.

Comment: This is saving photo in default album.which is same as app name

Comment: Yes that's fine but what if I don't want to create album and just want to post it on Wall. Is there any way ?